# How do I find the acceleration of the two boxes?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I have been having a lot of trouble with this problem.
I can’t correctly write the force equations for each box, or the free body diagram for the system and the boxes themselves.
I have been stuck for hours. If someone could help that would be really nice.
The question is here: Two identical boxes are placed on an inclined plane one attached to a pulley and one is pulling the the system down.
M1=M2=5kg
A. How do I find the acceleration of both boxes
B. How do I find the tension of the strings [image]

Comment: Homework and exercise is off topic here. Can you be more specific? show your effort on the problem and specify the step,you are having problem with?

Comment: I made changes to make it more specific, I also explained what I’m having trouble with

Comment: See if you can show from kinematics that the acceleration of a1 is twice the acceleration a2, and from the force balance on the lower pulley that the tension in the rope connected to M2 is twice the tension in the rope connected to M1.

Comment: @YanivArazi No you didn't explain what you're having trouble with. The questions you asked are the questions set in the problem. If you cannot even start to solve a problem, you need to go back and re-learn the basics of the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Write individual force balances on M1 and M2, involving T1, T2, a1, and a2.  Then show from kinematics that $a_1=2a_2$ and from a force balance on the lower pulley that $T_2=2T_1$.